# Do destroyed containers drop their loot?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I just survived the 3rd horde (21st night) but the zombies smashed a few of my containers (desk/box) that held a lot of the stuff that I had collected. I don't see it on the floor. Is it gone forever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upon destroying a container with items in it, it will leave a backpack on the ground. This backpack can be moved by running into it, and it does despawn after about a minute.  I've tested this in my game using a sink that contained some loot.    There is also a small [Steam post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/251570/discussions/0/2217311444341419165/) of someone who experienced the same thing as you. It appears that you've lost all of your items unfortunately.

[image: backpack]

[image: backpack gone]